# How to run tor service with snowflake?

Tags: tor

How to install and use tor with `snowflake` bridge on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some tries, I got it working.

First we need to install `tor`

```
sudo apt install tor
```

Then we need `golang`. The one in Ubuntu deb repository is a bit too old. But there is a snap package with `go` 1.18.

```
sudo snap install go
```

Download `snowflake` source

```
git clone https://git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/snowflake.git
```

Build it

```
cd snowflake/client/
go get
go build
```

Move it to `/opt` or another place if you like.

```
sudo mv ~/snowflake /opt
```

Now we need to configure tor to use `snowflake`.

Edit `/etc/tor/torrc` and add there:

```
UseBridges 1

ClientTransportPlugin snowflake exec /opt/snowflake/client/client

Bridge snowflake 192.0.2.3:1 url=https://snowflake-broker.torproject.net.global.prod.fastly.net/ front=cdn.sstatic.net ice=stun:stun.voip.blackberry.com:3478,stun:stun.altar.com.pl:3478,stun:stun.antisip.com:3478,stun:stun.bluesip.net:3478,stun:stun.dus.net:3478,stun:stun.epygi.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.net:3478,stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478,stun:stun.uls.co.za:3478,stun:stun.voipgate.com:3478,stun:stun.voys.nl:3478
```

**Note:** Other bridges should be removed if any.

Also we need to add `snowflake` to `apparmor`. Edit `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/tor` and add

```
/opt/snowflake/client/client Pix,
```

Restart `apparmor`

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```

After all this, you can start or restart tor, it should work with `snowflake`.

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions, after installing tor, install the snowflake-client

```
sudo apt install snowflake-client
```

Then edit the torrc:

```
UseBridges 1

ClientTransportPlugin snowflake exec /usr/bin/snowflake-client -url https://snowflake-broker.torproject.net.global.prod.fastly.net/ -front foursquare.com -ice stun:stun.l.google.com:19302,stun:stun.antisip.com:3478,stun:stun.bluesip.net:3478,stun:stun.dus.net:3478,stun:stun.epygi.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.com:3478,stun:stun.uls.co.za:3478,stun:stun.voipgate.com:3478,stun:stun.voys.nl:3478 -log /var/log/tor/snowflake-client.log

Bridge snowflake 192.0.2.3:80 2B280B23E1107BB62ABFC40DDCC8824814F80A72
Bridge snowflake 192.0.2.4:80 8838024498816A039FCBBAB14E6F40A0843051FA
```

you still may need to specify the client to apparmor.

```
/usr/bin/snowflake-client Pix,
```